# Reversing Order of List in Python

Tags: python, list

I have been given the following piece of code:

```
def two_pair(ranks):
    """If there are two pair, return the two ranks as a
    tuple: (highest, lowest); otherwise return None."""
    pair = kind(2,ranks)
    lowpair = kind(2, list(reversed(ranks)))
    if pair and lowpair != pair:
        return (pair,lowpair)
    else:
        return None
```

In the lowpair variable, why does `list()` need to be stated? Why can't you just say `reversed(ranks)`. `ranks` is a list. Is it not already implied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) returns an iterator, not a list. We need to explicitly convert that to a list, unless we just want to iterate it.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print reversed(a)        # <listreverseiterator object at 0x7fc57d746790>
```

That is why we have to use `list` to get the actual reversed list, like this

```
print list(reversed(a))  # [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want shorter code you could do `ranks[::-1]` instead of `list(reversed(ranks))`.

```
>>> ranks = [1,2,3]
>>> ranks[::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`reversed(ranks)` isn't a reversed list. It's an iterator:

```
>>> reversed([1, 2, 3])
<listreverseiterator object at 0x0000000001DDE9E8>
```

The `list` call is necessary to get a reversed list.